# Упрощение struct->delegate c#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть запись данного вида

```
private struct WindowProperties
{
    public Action WindowDrawDelegate;
}

dialog.StartModal(entry.Id, DialogHelper.DialogType.AssignElement, new WindowProperties
    {
        WindowDrawDelegate = DrawReassignOrRemoveElementAssignmentWindow
    },
    DialogResultCallback);

dialog.StartModal(entry.Id, DialogHelper.DialogType.DeleteAssignmentConfirmation, new WindowProperties
    {
        WindowDrawDelegate = DrawModalWindow
    },
    DialogResultCallback);
```

Если в WindowsProperties только одна запись, не может ли это как то быть упрощено?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Например, так:

```
private struct WindowProperties
{
    public Action WindowDrawDelegate;
    public WindowProperties(Action windowDrawDelegate)
    {
        WindowDrawDelegate = windowDrawDelegate;
    }
}

dialog.StartModal(
    entry.Id, DialogHelper.DialogType.AssignElement,
    new WindowProperties(DrawReassignOrRemoveElementAssignmentWindow),
    DialogResultCallback);
```

Ещё можно определить implicit operator `Action` → `WindowProperties`, но это наверное не очень правильно (хоть и укоротит код).